# Getting a tight enough upper bound for root mean square like quantity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds, mean-square-error

Given vectors $a,b, \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^n$, I am trying to get a good upper bound for

$$ 
\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n \big((a_i + \epsilon_i b_i)^p - a_i^p\big)^2}
$$

which depends on $\epsilon_G := max_{i=1,\dots,n} \epsilon_i$ and $p \in \mathbb{N}$

So far I have used the binomial formula and the identity for $a^p - b^p$ but the bounds obtained are not tight enough.

This is related to the equation I am working with

$$
E_{TG}(\phi, p) = || \big(\lambda\phi(x) + \epsilon(x)^T \nabla\phi(x^{t})\big)^p - (\lambda \phi(.))^p ||_G $$

where the $||.||_G$ norm is the norm of a function on a discrete grid G of coordinates defined as

$$
||\phi||_G = \sqrt{\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{x \in G} (\phi(x))^2}
$$

The function $\phi := v^T \psi$ where vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^D$ has  $||v|| = 1$, and $\psi: \mathbb{R}^n \xrightarrow{} \mathbb{R}^D$ is a set of basis functions(example, polynomial basis)

$x^t$ is a flow function which is known explicitly

$\epsilon_G = max_{x \in G} ||\epsilon(x)|| $

The upper bound I have obtained is

$$
E_{TG}(\phi, p) \leq C_{TG}(p, \lambda) \epsilon_G 
$$

where $C_{TG} = \left\lVert  ||J_{\psi}(.^t)||_2 \bigg(\sum_{i=0}^{p-1} ||\psi(T^t (.)||^{p-1-i}  ||\psi(.)||^i \lambda^i \bigg) \right\rVert _G$

where $J_\psi$ is the Jacobian of the basis functions and $||.||_2$ is the spectral norm.

The problem is when such a system is simulated with data and the Euler method for flow $T^t$, I get a constant which increases exponentially with increasing $p$ but growth $E_{TG}$ with respect to p is small. I would like to get an upper bound which tracks the growth of the error with $p$

Comment: Do you have a specific equation in mind? If not please show what you got and approximately what you want.

Comment: @person I have added the specific equation this is related to